# Let L be a linear mapping, then if $L(x) = L(L(x))$ for all $x$ then can we say that $x = L(x)$?

Tags: linear-transformations

> Let L be a linear mapping, then if $L(x) = L(L(x))$ for all $x$ then can we say that $x = L(x)$?

I think this should be true but I am not sure. Can you please help?

Comment: Take $L$ to be the constant functions $0.$

Answer (score 1):

$L(x)=L(L(x))$ is equivalent to $L(x-L(x))=0$, i.e., to
$$
x-L(x)\in \ker(L).
$$
If $\ker(L)=0$ then $L(x)=x$. However, if $\ker(L)$ is nontrivial, this need not follow.

Answer (score 1):

Every projection other than the identity is a counterexample to your claim, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Or $0$ as mentioned by Phicar...